# If a sequence of smooth functions converge in the Sobolev norm, what can one say about the limiting function?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

Let $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Sobolev space of $k$ times weakly differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, having finite Sobolev $p$ norm. 
Suppose $\{f_i\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, such 
that $f_i: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth 
($\mathcal{C}^{\infty} $) function for all $i$. Since $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$    is a Banach space (i.e., complete) this Cauchy sequence converges to some 
function $f$. My question is, what can one say about this function $f$?

Is it continuous? Is it differentiable? Can one conclude any of these facts 
under some additional hypothesis? 
Under what hypothesis can one say that the function $f$ has 
$k$ derivatives (the actual derivative, not the weak derivative)?

Secondly, is it possible to conclude under any reasonable hypothesis that 
the sequence $f_i$ converges to $f$ uniformly?

Comment: The smooth functions are dense, so $f$ is just an arbitrary function in $W^{k,p}$.

Comment: Actually, I think my question is not really precise. I meant is there a continuous (resp differentiable )representative in the equivalence class represented by [f]. The $W^{k,p}$ spaces are equivalence class of functions, where two functions are the same if they differ on a set of measure zero.

Comment: That's what I took you to mean, it doesn't change anything. There are plenty of discontinuous Sobolev functions, and all Sobolev functions can be approximated by smooth functions.

Comment: As Anthony Carapetis points out the answer in general is no. Sometimes you get good behavior on lower dimension sets, though. For instance, if $p > n-1$, then the sequence $\{f_i\}$ of regularizations of $f$ converges to $f$ uniformly on almost every $n-1$ hyperplane.

Comment: @Umberto: Thankyou, this is the sort of result I was looking for. Can you give me a reference for this fact "uniform convergence on almost every hyperplane" and possibly similar results of this nature?